# correct interpretation/understanding of this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, morphology, sentence-meaning

I have the following 2 sentences:

1- I did not see any *other* classmates, except/but Michael.

2- I did not see any classmates, except/but Michael

For the first sentence can we understand that the word **other** converts the expression in inclusive meaning that Michael is a classmate too?

For the second sentence, since the word **other** is missing, then does it mean that Michael is not a classmate?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. The "of" was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both sentences, the word *except* (and also *but*, when used like that) implies that Michael is one of the classmates. If Michael were not a classmate, you'd need to say something like

[1] *I did not see any of my classmates, but I did see Michael.*

Having said that, in both of your sentences there should be a determiner in fromt of *classmeates*. There are in fact many ways how they can be rewritten in order to be fully acceptable. Here are some, which all mean more or less the same thing:

[2]     a. *I did not see any other of my classmates except Michael.*
           b. *I did not see any of my other classmates except Michael.*
           c. *I did not see any other classmates except Michael.*
           d. *I did not see any of my classmates except Michael.*
           e. *I did not see any classmates except Michael.*

In all of these, instead of *except* you could use *but*. Also, in all of them, you could say *[except]/[but] **for** Michael*. In those which have *my classmates*, you could use some other determiner except *my*; for example, you could say *the classmates*. The placement of a comma after *classmates* is also a matter of style.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the help and examples. Is possible to use "if not" in the same way that except or but?

Comment: @GerCas:  No, you can't.  Here are some examples of how "if not" can be used:  "If not now, when?"  "If not Harry, who then?"  And these 3 from The Grammar Exchange:  "I'll pick you up at seven, if not earlier."

"Stir in the liquid slowly; if not, the mixture will not thicken."

"The pilot knew exactly what to do. If not, the plane would have crashed."

Comment: @GerCas You mean as in * *I did not see any other of my classmates if not Michael*? If so, no, you can't use *if not* that way. To express your statement as a conditional, you'd need to say something like *If it weren't for (me seeing) Michael, I wouldn't have seen any of my classmates (at all)*. But note that in this statement it is unclear if perhaps you might have eventually seen some other classmates in addition to Michael, and you seeing Michael was somehow the reason you managed to see these additional ones.

Comment: @GerCas The *if*-part could also be *If I hadn't seen  Michael.* In these constructions, you can't use *other* after *any* or before *classmates*. Indeed, the sentence *If I hadn't seen  Michael, I wouldn't have seen any other of my classmates (either)* does imply that you did eventually see some other classmates in addition to Michael.

Comment: @Wordster Excellent. Many thanks for your example a of "if not". I get the idea.

Comment: @linguisticturn  thanks a lot for your additionally examples to your original answer. I have clear now. Thanks for help and time.

Comment: @GerCas No problem!